# WPF application visiblity afte remote desktop

Tags: wpf, desktop, visible

i have a WPF application that sits on top of all other windows. 99% of the time it works perfectly however if i dial into my computer from another location using remote desktop and then close the connection and go back to the original computer, my application is not visible. checking the running processes i can see that it is still running however its not visible at all. I assume it has something to do with the remoting but i was wondering if there is some code i can run say every 20 seconds that sits on its own thread that checks whether it is visible and if not will execute some code whether by pInvoke or .NET to become visible again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to upgrade to .NET 3.5sp1.  There were some changes with remoting which lead to WPF applications being sent as bitmaps in remote desktop in all situations.

In earlier versions of the framework, there were problems with WPF applications causing very odd behavior when combined with remote desktop.

Another idea - make sure you're using the latest and greatest versions of your graphics drivers from your graphics card vendor.  WPF makes heavy use of DirectX, and this could potentially be a driver bug preventing the context from resetting appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Reed for your answehich is already reported r. I came to know that, its an OS bug which is already reported. This happens only on WPF application when we make the Allowtranspracy to true for the windows.